# Why a missing function parameter has a value of "[object Object]"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a signup modal window, that should appear under two circumstances:
a) a button is clicked on the webpage;
b) the webpage has "#modal" in the URL (e.g. mydomain/mypage.html#modal) - in this case the webpage should load with the modal window above it.

Scenario A works as follows:

- Html

```
    <a href='#' class='button signup' data-target='.signup-modal'>Find out more</a>
```

- JS + JQuery

```
$(function() {
    $('.signup').on('click', showModal);
});
```

Scenario B:

- JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    if(hash === '#modal'){
      showModal('.signup-modal');
    }
});
```

The `showModal` function works as follows:

```
function showModal(modalType) {
    var getTarget = $(this).data('target');
    if (!getTarget) {
        var target = modalType;
    } else {
        var target = getTarget;
    }    
        
    $(target).show();
    return false;
}
```

**This works.**
However, my previous attempt to this function was slightly different:

```
function showModal(modalType) {
    if (!modalType) {
        var target = $(this).data('target');
    } else {
        var target = modalType;
    }    
        
    $(target).show();
    return false;
}
```

**This didn't work with Scenario A.**
I thought, that if the function has no parameter specified, it will get `modalType = undefined`, and then `var target = $(this).data('target');`. I added `alert(target)` and found out, that after clicking on the button, I was getting `[object Object]` as the value of `target`.

Can anyone please explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First argument of an event handler callback is the event object. So `if (!modalType)` will never be true.

You could check if it is a string for the selector version. Something like:

```
if ( typeof modalType !== 'string' )
```

Here's a simplified example:

```js
function doStuff(thing){
   if(!thing){
      // won't get called in the two scenarios used
      console.log('no thing');
      return
   }

   if(typeof thing === 'string'){
       console.log('Argument is string:', thing)
   }else{
      // thing is event object
      const event = thing;
      console.log('Event type:', event.type);
      console.log('Target:', event.target)
      // also `this` will be the element instance event occurred on
      console.log('Tagname:', this.tagName);
   }

}

$('button').on('click', doStuff);

doStuff('SomeString')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click me</button>
```